# Kafka Connect JDBC failed on JsonConverter

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am working on a design  MySQL -> Debezium -> Kafka -> Flink -> Kafka -> Kafka Connect JDBC  -> MySQL. Following is sample message i write from Flink (I also tried using Kafka console producer as well)

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "id"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": true,
        "field": "name"
      }
    ],
    "optional": true,
    "name": "user"
  },
  "payload": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Smith"
  }
}
```

but connect failed on JsonConverter

```
DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:338)
```

I have debugged and in method `public SchemaAndValue toConnectData(String topic, byte[] value)` value is null. My sink configurations are:

```
{
    "name": "user-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "user",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?verifyServerCertificate=false",
        "connection.user": "root",
        "connection.password": "root",        
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_value"
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an issue is not related with the value serialization (of Kafka message). It is rather problem with the key of the message.

What is your `key.converter`? I think it is the same like `value.converter` (`org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`). Your key might be simple `String`, that doesn't contain `schema`, `payload`

Try to change `key.converter` to `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`

For Kafka Connect you set default `Converters`, but you can also set specific one for your particular Connector configuration (that will overwrite default one). For that you have to modify your config request:

```js
{
    "name": "user-sink",
    "config": {
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "user",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?verifyServerCertificate=false",
        "connection.user": "root",
        "connection.password": "root",        
        "auto.create": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_value"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i want to use the key converter similar to value. What i need to change in my request. Because in other sink its working when i dont involve flink.